How can I get closer enough to the mesh?
I have this problem: I cannot zoom in close enough to work on a details on the mesh before the mesh dissapears.
I think it is something related to focal distance or something like that, but the tutos I saw relate to the camera, and I have no camera in my scene (at least I don´t see it in the outliner).
Which is the way to do it?
I add a video for you to see the problem.
Thanks a lot in advance :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOYr-rzo6kBiuGst4HtQOqy8vmsrqRHk/view?usp=sharing

In Object mode, on the N menu, there's a tab called 'view'. The top parameters are what controls when objects disappear in the workspace iirc
